# css Styling in Asp.Net MVC Project

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am facing some issues with css styling MVC application i am working on, and have not fount any answer online so i thought i ask maybe someone came across similar situation.

Basically if i Start Debugging i get all the modifications that were performed on the Style-sheet, If I run project with Start without Debugging then the medications on css file will not appear in the view.

```
.nav-linksmall {
color: #333;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 300;
padding: 4px 12px;
```

}

Any Idea way.?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL F5 to rule out caching? It would be useful if you say everything you tried

Comment: Clear the cache Ctrl+Shift+delete , it should work

Comment: Thanks, It is the cache.